# PHP WordPress - Switch/Toggle

Tags: php, html, wordpress, switch-statement, toggle

I currently have a filter set it up for my conferences list, everything is working perfectly. I want to add a toggle/switch that when is on, shows all the conferences (even the past ones). Right now is only showing the ones starting from today ('value' => date ('Ymd'),). I was thinking to create a function that checks if the switch is on or off and it depends on the answer it gives the 'value' a different value. Right now is only getting the else value of function show_all ($pega = date ('Ymd'). But I've tried everything and it's not working, maybe I am doing something wrong. Thank you in advance. PHP code[HTML code Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsJ3T.png)

```
//FUNCTIONS CHECKING IF SWITCH IS ON OR OFF
function show_all() {
  if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $pega = date('Ymd');
  } else {
    $pega = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2017-02-02 17:02:03'));
  }
  return $pega;
}

//FUNCTION SHOWING THE CONFERENCES 
function get_future_conferences() {
  $pega2 = show_all();
  $args = array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'conference', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'meta_key' => 'conference_start_date', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_query' => array('key' => 'conference_start_date', 'value' => $pega2, 'compare' => '>=', ), );
  $conferences = get_posts($args);
  return $conferences;
}
```

Ps.: I am using date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2017-02-02 17:02:03')); to show the past conferences. If I add that to the 'value' manually it shows the past ones perfectly.

Comment: https://globebusociety.s3.amazonaws.com/new.png (php code image)

Comment: //FUNCTIONS CHECKING IF SWITCH IS ON OR OFF
function show_all () {
 
 if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
  $pega = date('Ymd');
  
 }else{
  $pega = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2017-02-02 17:02:03'));
 }
 return $pega;
}

Comment: //FUNCTION SHOWING THE CONFERENCES
function get_future_conferences() { 
 $pega2 = show_all(); 
 $args = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type'   => 'conference',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_key'    => 'conference_start_date',
  'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
  'order'       => 'ASC',
  'meta_query'  => array(
   'key'     => 'conference_start_date',
   'value'   => $pega2,
   'compare' => '>=',
  ),
 );
 $conferences = get_posts( $args );
 return $conferences;
}

Comment: <label class="switch"> 
          <input type="checkbox" name="switch">
          <div class="slider round"></div>
       </label>